# python how to post string without " ' "

Tags: python, json, string, python-requests

I want to send string data in python. however, it sends the 'character as it is a string when sending.

```
    keys = '"' + keywords.lower().replace(' ,', '","') + '"'
    keys = "[" + keys + "]"

[
        {
            "keywords": keys,

        }
    ]
```

result

```
'keywords': '["xxxxx","xxxxxxxy"]'
```

i want this result

```
'keywords': ["xxxxx","xxxxxxxy"]
```

without '

how can I do that?

I'm sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Comment: What are the contents of `keywords`? Not the one in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can't just say:

```
keys = '"' + keywords.lower().replace(' ,', '","') + '"'
keys = "[" + keys + "]"
# keys == '["xxxxx","xxxxxxxy"]'
```

The `["xxxxx","xxxxxxxy"]` that you want is a collection strings, while the `'["xxxxx","xxxxxxxy"]'` that you get is one single string - a collection of characters like `'[', '"', 'x', 'x', ...`. You need a different *data type* - `keys` must be a `list` of strings, not a single string.

Depending on what the initial `keywords` is, you could try:

```
keys = [k.strip() for k in keywords.lower().split(',')]
```

Comment: thanks thats work but result keywords': ['prayer', 'pray', 'hand'] but i want keywords': ["prayer","pray","hand"] how can i do that?                           ' to " and no space

Comment: @bymechul, these are literally exactly the same. The kind of quotation mark doesn't make any difference whatsoever. The space doesn't make any difference either - you could add more spaces or remove them - they'll all be different representations of the same Python list

Comment: It doesn't accept when I try to post. I sent [{ 'keywords': ['prayer', 'pray', 'hand', 'church'],}]
the original should be sent [{"keywords":["prayer","pray","hand","church"],}]

Comment: @bymechul, weird... Anyway, if your keywords don't contain spaces, you can remove the spaces: `str(keys).replace(' ', '')`

Comment: not work as I said.  not this ['prayer', 'pray'] thats work ["prayer", "pray"]

Answer (score 0):

You're constructing a string that just happens to look how Python prints its lists, when it seems what you really want to do is have an actual list.

Instead of

```
keys = '"' + keywords.lower().replace(' ,', '","') + '"'
keys = "[" + keys + "]"
```

you could just do

```
keys = keywords.lower().split(' ,')
```

which will give you a list containing your words.